# Mapping interval values on ordinal scale in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

Is there an easy way to map interval values on a ordinal color scale in D3.js instead of using if-clauses? I would like to map values on a ordinal scale that exceeded a particular level.

[image: Ordinal scale with interval values]

Comment: How about these examples: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4573883 & http://eyeseast.github.io/visible-data/2013/08/27/responsive-legends-with-d3/. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: The threshold example is really nice and fits to my problem. Thanks for the examples.

Comment: You can place your advice within the answer section if you want.

Comment: re-posted as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These examples might be helpful:

[Threshold Key](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4573883) - demonstrates how to construct a key from a threshold scale

[Responsive Legends with D3](http://eyeseast.github.io/visible-data/2013/08/27/responsive-legends-with-d3/)